# how to store archival records in database?

Tags: database, oracle, database-design

I have an archival table e.g. "users_archive". Its structure like archive_id, username, phone and so on. Also i have a table "Users". Every month, depends on some conditions, i need add again and again users to the users_archive table, so some records may get into the table, and some records may not. 
For example, if i add about 20 mln users to users_archive table every month, only 3 mln of them has changes, and rest of them doesn't change. The point is, i store all records(changed and not changed) every month, instead just store changed records.
So how can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Assuming you are using an `insert/select` to add them, add a where clause to your select to only add changed records. What are changed records? Those that have a matching unique key but different attributes.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid comment looks like answer.  How did you implement you archive process ?